# if only one record is return linq output is wrong c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

following code will return newly inserted records `id` from my `Device` table.

```
var newIds = context.Devices.Take(deviceDataList.Count)
                    .OrderByDescending(t => t.Id)
                    .Select(t => t.Id)
                    .ToList();
```

if `deviceDataList.Count` is more than `1` it works fine.

but when it is only one it is returning wrong first `id` instead latest inserted.

Comment: You're calling `Take` *before* ordering. Try changing it to `OrderByDescending(t => t.Id).Take(deviceDataList.Count)`. Otherwise you're saying "I'll take the first N of them in any ordering you like, then order those N values".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First order and then take. `Take` retrieves the records by the order they are in the collection (perhaps just in the disk or any other reasoning of the database). If you want to be sure it is by the `Id` then do so.

```
var result = context.Devices.OrderByDesending(t => Id)
                    .Take(deviceDataList.Count)
                    .Select(t => t.Id);
```

Comment: This is the answer, sort your list first then take.